# Android Drag and Drop (not able to shuffle images)

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to implement android drag and drop.I am getting output:
   I do have two layout,From first layout i can drag icon or image to next layout .My issue is am not able to shuffle my images and merge the views.Any advice will be helpful to me.
Thank You

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView myImage,myImage1,myImage2,myImage3;
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG = "The Android Logo";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG1 = "The Android Logo1";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG2 = "The Android Logo2";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG3 = "The Android Logo3";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        myImage1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        myImage2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
        myImage3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);

        // Sets the tag
        myImage.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);
        myImage1.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG1);
        myImage2.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG2);
        myImage3.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG3);

        // set the listener to the dragging data
        myImage.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());
        myImage1.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());
        myImage2.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());
        myImage3.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());

        findViewById(R.id.toplinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    }

    private final class MyClickListener implements OnLongClickListener {

        // called when the item is long-clicked
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // create it from the object's tag
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)view.getTag());

            String[] mimeTypes = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
            ClipData data = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

            view.startDrag( data, //data to be dragged
                            shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                            view, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                            0   //no needed flags
                          );


            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }   
    }

    class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_shape);
        Drawable targetShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.target_shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            // Handles each of the expected events
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;

            //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(targetShape);   //change the shape of the view
                break;

            //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);   //change the shape of the view back to normal
                break;

            //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // if the view is the bottomlinear, we accept the drag item
                  if(v == findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear)) {
                      View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                      ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                      viewgroup.removeView(view);

                      //change the text
                    //  TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    //  text.setText("The item is dropped");

                     GridLayout containView = (GridLayout) v;
                      containView.addView(view);
                      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  } else {
                      View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      Context context = getApplicationContext();
                      Toast.makeText(context, "You can't drop the image here", 
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      break;
                   }
                  break;

            //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);   //go back to normal shape

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're not able to shuffle your images and merge the views it's because you're not handling the drop events correctly.

Take a look at this Drag and Drop open source example:

https://github.com/theredsunrise/AndroidCoolDragAndDropGridView

Comment: Thank you..I have one query i just want split Screen Top Down ..I mean from First Screen i want to drag images to next Screen..Not pager..Any advice will be helpful